# How can I run a conditional neural network in Python (analogous to a clogit in R / Stata)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, statistics

I am looking to train a neural network in Keras (or tensorflow if required) that predicts which three players are designated [stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_stars_(ice_hockey)) in each NHL hockey game. My X matrix consists of standard box score information for each player, e.g. minutes played, goals, assists, etc. and target variable can be one of four classes (0 - not in best three, 1 - best player, 2 - second best player, 3 - third best player).

So far this is a very standard problem and a vanilla neural network does a reasonable job at predicting the probabilities that a player will be designated a star. The problem is that I want to add a constraint which forces the probabilities within a single game to sum to one (across all players) for classes 1, 2, 3, whilst maintaining the softmax constraint that each for each player the probability of all classes must also sum to one. I note that the [conditional logistic  regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_logistic_regression) model achieves this for binary classification, but I haven't seen this implemented within a machine learning framework.

I believe this will require a custom activation function, which Keras can implement. However I am uncertain of how the math / code will look.

Sample code that I've run so far is this:

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# generate data
games, m = 50, 40
X = np.zeros((games * m, 11))
Y = np.zeros((games * m, 4))

for i in range(games):
    rowStart, rowEnd = (i) * m, (1 + i) * m
    X[rowStart:rowEnd, 0] = i
    X[rowStart:rowEnd, 1:] = np.random.rand(m, 10)  

    for j in range(1, 4):
        rowInd = rowStart + np.random.randint(0, m)
        while np.sum(Y[rowInd]) != 0.0:
            rowInd = rowStart + np.random.randint(0, m)
        Y[rowInd, j] = 1    

# run model   
mod2 = Sequential()
mod2.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1]-1,)))
mod2.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
mod2.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
mod2.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
hist = mod2.fit(X[:,1:], Y, epochs=10, batch_size=m)
```

Comment: I could not understand the constraints you mentioned. Could you please give a numerical example of what the situation looks like?

Comment: So a neural network makes sure that the class probabilities sum to one for each player (row/observation) - this is obviously a good thing. I need to add the constraint that for classes 1, 2, 3 they sum to one for each game. The intuitive reason: only one player will be designated the one-star (best player) rating, so the probabilities for a given game should be constrained to one. I've made the simplifying assumption that each game contains exactly 40 players.

Comment: Then if I understand it correctly, I think the input of your model should be the whole game, not just a single player, right? Because I interpret the problem like this: given the stats of a set of players in a game, predict the best, second-best and third-best players (or predict the probs of best, second-best and third-best for **each player** in the **given input game**). Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Although I'm not sure how you would squash all 40 players from each game into one row? The X matrix is now n x 11*40? What abut the Y matrix?

I was setting the batch size = 40 = all players from one game. I was hoping I could force probabilities for each class to sum to one across each batch, i.e. 100% that someone gets best player in each game

Answer (score 0):

I really like your idea of having a "bidirectional softmax". I'm sorry, but after a while I was able to prove that such a softmax is not possible in a general case (if interested I can add a simplified description why).

But there are still other ways of solving this without a "bidirectional softmax" and without violating your restrictions. I suggest you use the complete game 40 players with 10 features as input, and rank each of the 40 players as output. 
Instead of classifying each player into 4 classes, I suggest you give each player a score (for example -1 for not in best three, 0 for third best player, 1 for second best player and 2 for best player). At prediction, you can then just choose the player with the largest score as best player, second largest as second best, third largest as third best and the rest as not in best three.
This way you don't violate you restriction that each player should get a "class", and only one player for first, second and third best.

see below for a minimal working example:

```py
# import packages
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten#, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# generate data
games, m = 50, 40
X = np.zeros((games, m, 11))
Y = np.zeros((games, m))

for i in range(games):
    X[i, :, 0] = i
    X[i, :, 1:] = np.random.rand(m, 10)  

    y_indexes = np.arange(m)
    np.random.shuffle(y_indexes)
    # score players
    Y[i,y_indexes[0]] = 2 # best
    Y[i,y_indexes[1]] = 1 # second best
    Y[i,y_indexes[2]] = 0 # third best
    Y[i,y_indexes[3:]] = -1 # not best

# run model   
inputs = Input(shape=(m,10)) # -1 as we dont use fist column (game number)
inputs_flatten = Flatten()(inputs)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs_flatten)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(m, activation=None)(x)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)

adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(X[:,:,1:], Y, epochs=20, batch_size=10)

# predict third, second and best players for the first game
# the print number, is the player number
Y_pred = model.predict(X[0:1,:,1:])
print(np.argsort(Y_pred.reshape(-1))[-3:])
#[7 29 19]
# True best players fist game
print(np.argsort(Y[0,:].reshape(-1))[-3:])
#[7 29 19]
```

note that this model architecture is deeper and has more node than is recommend for such an small data-set (only 50 events, one each game).

Comment: This is a good solution, but in my case, I require probabilistic predictions, not predicted class. My current (hacky) approach is to iteratively divide the by sum of rows, i.e. softmax, then by the sum of the columns. Eventually the probabilities converge to state where the sum of all classes for a player = 1 and the sum for classes (1,2,3) across all players =1. However this is unsatisfactory for a number of reasons, most of all because I can't seem to incorporate this process into a keras activation function.